# How to pass Value in export default

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I have one function like

```
    export default (
  <Route name="App" path="/" handler={App}>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={require('./pages/PageNotFound')} />
    <Route handler={TaskList} data={data} >
    </Route>
    {data.map(task =>
              <Route name={task.PageName}  handler={require(task.PageUrl)}>
             </Route>
          )}

  </Route>
);
```

I want to pass the data to this code so how I can convert this code as a function can anyone please help to pass in it

Comment: That's not a function, is it?

Comment: ya you are right its not a function I have tried many ways to convet this code in function but not able to find out the correct syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting a `React.Component`. Just make it a function so that you give it parameters that allow for passing arguments:

```
export default (data =>
//              ^^^^^^^
  <Route name="App" path="/" handler={App}>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={require('./pages/PageNotFound')} />
    <Route handler={TaskList} data={data}>
    </Route>
    { data.map(task =>
        <Route name={task.PageName} handler={require(task.PageUrl)}>
        </Route>
    ) }
  </Route>
);
```